# Computing Many Differences in a Nested List

Tags: list-manipulation

Consider a nested list. For example:

```
{{-1.}, {1.99196}, {-0.787432}, {-1.3562, -1., 1.3562}, {-1.77689}, {1.49709}, 
 {-1.}, {1.13944}, {-0.720512}, {-1., -0.84243, 1.68838}, {-0.667961}, 
 {-1.89495, -0.700922, 1.16473}, {-1.}, {1.21298}, {-0.750015}, {-1., -1., 1.}, 
 {-1.3879}, {1.83929}, {-1.}, {1.19503}, {-1.95681}, {1.26995}, {-1.25905}, 
 {1.}, {-1.}, {1.40958}, {-0.824416}, {-1.6483, -1., 1.}, {-1.59721}, {1.}, 
 {-1., 1., 1.83929}, {0.877628}, {-0.562781}, {-1., -0.578329, 1.91893}, 
 {-0.543689}, {-1.63758, -0.553375, 1.2279}, {-1.58235, -1., -0.631973}}`
```

I am wondering if it is possible to compute the differences of the elements in the lists. For example, if the nested list was just

```
{{-1.}, {1.99196}, {-0.787432}, {-1.3562, -1., 1.3562}, {-1.77689}, {1.49709}, 
 {-1.}, {1.13944}, {-0.720512}, {-1., -0.84243, 1.68838}}
```

I would get:

```
{.3562, 2.3562, 0.15757, 2.53081}.
```

In other words, I would like the differences of the elements in lists that have more than one element.

I have tried some applications of `Differences`, but it is not quite working as expected. Any help and/or ideas are immensely appreciated.

Comment: How about `Differences /@ list // Flatten`?

Comment: @jjc385 This works wonderfully, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you want to take [`Differences`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Differences.html) of all nested lists with more than one element.

```
list = {{-1.}, {1.99196}, {-0.787432}, {-1.3562, -1., 1.3562}, {-1.77689}, {1.49709}, {-1.}, {1.13944}, {-0.720512},{-1., -0.84243, 1.68838}};

Differences /@ list
```

> ```
> {{}, {}, {}, {0.3562, 2.3562}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {0.15757, 2.53081}}
> ```

Notice that `Differences` applied to a singleton list yields `{}`.  You can get rid of the empty lists and flatten this into one list using `Flatten` :

```
Differences /@ list // Flatten
```

> ```
> {0.3562, 2.3562, 0.15757, 2.53081}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If your list is called `L`, try:

`Differences@Flatten[L/.{_}->Nothing]`

I do have an extra element compared to you, though. Is that a mistake on your part, or mine?

Comment: Your mistake. It should be `Flatten[Differences /@ (L /. {_} -> Nothing)]`